# Merge dataset without common variable (By)?

Tags: sas

Currently I have two datasets with similar variable lists. Each dataset has a procedure variable. I want to compare the frequency of the procedure variable between datasets. I created a flag in both datasets to id the source dataset, and was going to merge but don't have a common identifier. How do I merge a dataset without deleting any observations? This isn't just a simple `Merge` without a `By` function, right?

Currently have:

```
 Data.a       Data.b 
   pproc    proc1_numb
    70           9
    71          15
    77          24
    80          80
    81          42
    83          71
    86          66
    87          125
    121         159
    125         242
```

Want Output:

```
pproc freq
9     1
15    1
24    1
42    1
66    1
70    1
71    2
77    1
80    2
81    1
83    1
86    1
87    1
121   1
125   2
159   1
242   1
```

Comment: Use a `set` statement.  Am I missing something?

Comment: So, just 
data new 
set a b; ?

Comment: What BellevueBob said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you should just concatenate the two datasets into one and rename the variable.  Then you can use PROC MEANS to get the frequencies. Something like this:

```
data all;
  set a
      b(rename=(proc1_numb=pproc));
run;

proc means nway data=all noprint;
  class pproc;
  output out=want(drop=_type_ rename=(_freq_=freq));
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @BellevueBob, that appears to solve it. I realized my original output lay-out was incorrect. But, using the flags for data.a and data.b created a different frequency count--as I really needed the frequency for procedure X by each dataset. Thanks again!